# How to ignore HTTPS Only Azure Appservice custom domain setting for Always on

Tags: asp.net-core, https, azure-web-app-service, app-startup, application-warmup

I have a ASP.Net Core 2.2 site running as an Azure AppService. As part of the configuration, I have a custom domain with the **HTTPS only** setting turned on.

I also have the **Always on** setting turned on on my Appservice.

According to this article
https://ruslany.net/2017/11/most-common-deployment-slot-swap-failures-and-how-to-fix-them/ the **Always on** setting will be ignored when **HTTPS only** is on and as a result, my site is always doing a cold start with the first call.

According to the same article, a rule condition can be set in the web.config to not process the **Redirect to HTTPS** rule if a {warmup_request} is processed.

However, my **HTTPS only** is set on the custom domain in Azure and not as a rule in the web.config.

I am setting RouteOptions in startup.cs with the following code:

```
services.Configure<RouteOptions>(options =>
{
    options.LowercaseUrls = true;
});
```

and believe that the rule condition can be done here as well using `options.ConstraintMap()` but I am unsure as to the syntax or method required to represent the following:

```
  <match url="(.*)" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{WARMUP_REQUEST}" pattern="1" negate="true" />
    <add input="{REMOTE_ADDR}" pattern="^100?\." negate="true" />
    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Any help on how to do this will be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From the time this article was written the "https only" has been added as a built-in feature of app services so there is no need to use this rewrite rule anymore.

As to how to minimize the cold start for your application - you may want to consider adding appinit configuration to the web.config as described in [App Service Warm-Up Demystified](https://michaelcandido.com/app-service-warm-up-demystified/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer @ruslany

Is there an Azure appsetting that I can use rather than the web.config?